# .NET Only draw the outline of a GraphicsPath

Tags: .net, graphics

I have created a simple GraphicsPath (a rounded rect), it is nothing special.

Now I would like to only draw a black line around it (with "inset", not "outset"... the path should not become biggger), and I don't want to fill the path.

Is there a quick way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
        Dim nPen As New Pen(uBorderColor, 1)
        With nPen
            .Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset
        End With

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(uBitmap)
            g.DrawPath(nPen, uPathBorder)
        End Using
```